# Unique email address validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, email

I've been adapting unique email validation codes I saw from tutorial and other posts. However, nothing seems to work perfectly for my code.

```
public function register_client($post_obj) 
{
    //client registration
    $record = array
    (
        'first_name'        => $post_obj['c_fname'],
        'last_name'         => $post_obj['c_lname'],
        'email_address'     => $post_obj['c_eadd'],
        'password'          => $post_obj['c_pword'],
        'address'           => $post_obj['c_add'],
        'tagline'           => $post_obj['c_tagline'],
        'profile'           => $post_obj['c_profile'],
        'interests'         => $post_obj['c_interest'],
        'billing_mode'      => $post_obj['c_bmode']
    );
    $this->db->insert('client', $record);
}
```

in my controller i have this:

```
    public function client_signup_submit() 
{
    // completes client registration

    /*$post_email = $this->input->post('c_eadd');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_eadd', 'Email Address', 'required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email|callback_check_duplicate_email[' . $post_email . ']');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_duplicate_email', 'This email already exits. Please write a new email.');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    // validation failed then do that
    $this->load->view('client_signup');
     } else */
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('c_eadd',Email,'trim|xss_clean|required|valid_email|callback_check_email_exists');
    $this->inspire_model->register_client($_POST);
    redirect("in/client?message=Client Account Registration Completed.");
}
```

I have commented several lines as they did not work anyway. I checked my system/libraries/form_validation and it seems that it is properly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do what the docs say: `is_unique[users.email]` where `users` is the table and `email` is the field you are checking against. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('c_eadd', 
    'Email Address',
    'required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

Comment: This seems to work because whenever I type same email add for  testing, the email add field is highlighted in yellow. But no message is shown, and also, the form is still submitted..

Comment: Oh I got it. I did: $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_eadd', 'Email Address', 'required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email|is_unique[client.email_address]');
   
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
  echo '<script language="javascript">alert("The email address you entered has already been taken.Please enter a different one.");</script>';
  $this->load->view('client_signup');
   } else {       
  $this->in_model->register_client($_POST); However, I wanted to alert the user just after entering the same email address. In the solution I could do, it still proceeds until the last field..